# Is prefs a predefined keyword when nesting method calls in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I am working through a book on Cocoa and Objective-C.  In the example for nested method calls:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:[prefs format]];
```

I am assuming that prefs is the return type for the nested method call to format...is this correct ?

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, in that case prefs will be an instance of an object. The return type will be an NSString *, since that's what stringWithFormat: takes. If it's part of a wider example then look for a declaration of the 'prefs' object. If it's just a throwaway line then you'll have to trust me for now. Rest assured: [object message] always sends that message to that object. The return type is defined by the message declaration and is assumed to be 'id' if the declaration can't be found.

It's not a particularly safe bit of code, by the way. If the result of [prefs format] contains any formatting characters then NSString will attempt to access things on the call stack that aren't there.

Comment: The fact that the method is called -format potentially means that a formatting string might be what it returns. It would seem a bit pointless though if it has no actual  format specifiers in it.

Comment: What a difference a day makes!  Looking at this now and reading your answer, I've got it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, the return type is only shown in the function declaration.  Prefs is the name of the object whose method is being called (or the receiver, in Obj-C speak).  In a Java-type syntax, the line would look like

```
NSString.stringWithFormat(prefs.format());
```

Comment: Ah, thank you for the Java code!  Coming from a C#/Java background, so Obj-C is a little strange.